# Applying xslt template one after the other for removing empty nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have written one xslt to transform one xml. But the resulting xml may have some empty nodes depending on the source XMl.

Now i want to remove those empty nodes with no values. I have found some expressions wild card expressions to remove the empty tags. But i am not able to apply the same to my existing xslt.

How can i define multiple xsl templates in one sheet so that first one will transform my source xml and the second one will take the out put of first transformation and remove the empty elements or nodes

Source XML

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="TTT.xsl"?>
<SourceXML>
    <Tag1>Val</Tag1>
    <Tag2></Tag2>
    <Tag3>
        <Tag4></Tag4>
        <Tag5></Tag5>
    </Tag3>
</SourceXML>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" /> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <TargetXML>
            <TagT1>
                <xsl:value-of select=".//Tag1" />
            </TagT1>
            <TagT2>
                <xsl:value-of select=".//Tag2" />
            </TagT2>
            <TagT3>
                <TagT4>
                    <xsl:value-of select=".//Tag3/Tag4" />
                </TagT4>
                <TagT5>
                    <xsl:value-of select=".//Tag3/Tag5" />
                </TagT5>
            </TagT3>
        </TargetXML>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<TargetXML>
    <TagT1>Val</TagT1>
    <TagT2></TagT2>
    <TagT3>
        <TagT4></TagT4>
        <TagT5></TagT5>
    </TagT3>
</TargetXML>
```

But i want to get an output to be like this

```
<TargetXML>
    <TagT1>Val</TagT1>
</TargetXML>
```

Could any one please explain how to achieve the same

Comment: "*How can i define multiple xsl templates in one sheet so that first one will transform my source xml and the second one will take the out put of first transformation and remove the empty elements or nodes*" I don't think you *need* to do this in two passes; you can probably adjust the first transformation to leave out the empty or nodes. But we would need to see what the first transformation actually does in order to be sure; in your example, where it does practically nothing except rename a few tags, this would be rather trivial.

Comment: Yes... It will not make any sense in the example which i have provided. But in real scenario i am working with a huge xml and to check each and every node for empty values during the first pass doesn't looks good. I will have to add if conditions on each node. So i was thinking whether there will be an easy way to do this.

Comment: "*I will have to add if conditions on each node.*" I am not at all sure that would be necessary. There's usually a more elegant way to treat the empty nodes (or the non-empty ones) in a more general way. Anyway, I have posted an answer that does what you ask for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer, you can store the results of the first pass in a variable, then apply more templates to the result, passing only nodes with actual values:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- first pass -->
<xsl:template match="/" mode="first-pass">
    <TargetXML>
        <TagT1>
            <xsl:value-of select=".//Tag1" />
        </TagT1>
        <TagT2>
            <xsl:value-of select=".//Tag2" />
        </TagT2>
        <TagT3>
            <TagT4>
                <xsl:value-of select=".//Tag3/Tag4" />
            </TagT4>
            <TagT5>
                <xsl:value-of select=".//Tag3/Tag5" />
            </TagT5>
        </TagT3>
    </TargetXML>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">    
    <!-- apply first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="first-pass"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- final output -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($first-pass)/*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[normalize-space(descendant::text()) or descendant-or-self::*/@*[string()]]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[string()]">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```