# Is it possible to apply template to copy of element?

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to apply template on copy of element?
Let say I have this XML:

```
<root>
  <a name="a1">
    A1
    <b name="b1">B1</b>
  </a>
  <b name="b2">B2</b>
  <a name="a2">
    <b name="b3">B3</b>
  </a>
  <b name="b4">B4</b>
  <a name="a3">
    <b name="b5">B5</b>
  </a>
</root>
```

and want to turn it into this XML:

```
<root>
  <a name="a1">
    A1
    <b name="b1">B1</b>
    <b name="b2">B2</b>
  </a>
  <a name="a2">
    <b name="b3">B3</b>
    <b name="b4">B4</b>
  </a>
  <a name="a3">
    <b name="b5">B5</b>
  </a>
</root>
```

and than apply this templates on new structure:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  1<xsl:apply-templates/>2
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="a">
  3<xsl:apply-templates select="b[2]"/>4
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="b[not(position()=2)]">
  5<xsl:apply-templates/>6
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="b[2]">
  7<xsl:apply-templates/>8
</xsl:template>
```

so output should be:

```
1
  3
    A1
    5B16
    7B28
  4
  3
    5B36
    7B48
  4
  3
    5B56
  4
2
```

**Important thing is I want to use normal templates on new structure**

So far I have this but it doesn't work (doesn't recognize new structure)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
1
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
2
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="a">
3
    <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::b[1]">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="aaa"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
4
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="b"/>
<xsl:template match="b[not(position()=2)]" mode="aaa">
  5<xsl:apply-templates/>6
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="b[2]" mode="aaa">
  7<xsl:apply-templates/>8
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you want to process your input in two passes, you must save the result of the first transformation to a variable or to a file. Then apply the templates of the second transformation to that. Note that in XSLT 1.0, the interim result in a variable needs to be converted from a result-tree-fragment to a node-set before it can be processed again - see an example here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471442/applying-xslt-template-one-after-the-other-for-removing-empty-nodes/28473525#28473525

Comment: thnx,i will study this :) 
tell me, is it possible to apply template to new xsl:element?

Comment: You can apply templates to elements held in the variable or in the interim file. It does not matter how these elements were created.